# Developing an ecommerce application by some udemy course. Got some error in spring security

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, application.properties

this is my SecurityConfiguration.java file

```
package com.luv2code.ecommerce.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy;
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    //protect endpoint /api/orders
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/orders/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    
    //add CORS filters
    http.cors();
    
    //add content negotiation strategy
    http.setSharedObject(ContentNegotiationStrategy.class, new
            HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());
    
    //force a non-empty response body for 401's to make the response more friendly
    
    Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
    
    return http.build();
}

}
```

written the exact code but getting these errors...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/luv2code/ecommerce/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.luv2code.ecommerce.SpringBootEcommerceApplication.main(SpringBootEcommerceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta.authenticationEntryPoint(Okta.java:133) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(Okta.java:81) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
at com.luv2code.ecommerce.config.SecurityConfiguration.filterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
at com.luv2code.ecommerce.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$0() ~[classes/:na]
at com.luv2code.ecommerce.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
at com.luv2code.ecommerce.config.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain() ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
... 33 common frames omitted

dependencies..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-ecommerce</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-ecommerce</name>
<description>Spring Boot Ecommerce Project</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Dependencies with versions? Please clean-up your trace snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a version mismatch between your boot and Okta versions:
https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#spring-boot-version-compatibility

By the way, boot `3.0.2` has been released (you might use that instead of `3.0.2-SNAPSHOT`).

Answer (score 0):

Your octa (starter) version should comply with spring boot version. [See compatibility](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#spring-boot-version-compatibility)